# Use data from a database to redirect to a new page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I am using PHP, HTML and a mySQL database.

My requirements:

1. Query for some data from the database and print it out.
2. Compare the data with some pre-defined values.
3. If the value is not in the range, raise a notification alert box.
4. Once, the user clicks 'OK'--> Open up a new webpage.

For example:

- The query result '199' is stored in `$result`.
- If $result is less than 200 (true in this case) then present an `alert`.
- Once the user clicks 'OK' in the `alert` load a new HTML page.

I am confused how to approach this.

I am able to get `$result` with a php script and display it.

Beyond that I am not able to use `$result` for comparison.

Comment: @devpro seems like my "fries" comment got deleted. It's an oldie but a goodie, really. Meh, "let them eat cake" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can **send queries** to server using ajax calls
2. **Compare the results** with predefined values
3. **If a match** occurs,insert the code

```js
alert('message');
window.location = '/some/url';
```